# Silverlight 3 : Datagrid - Editing a cell shows a "Property set method not found." message

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-3.0

I have a silverlight datagrid control bound to a `Dictionary<string, string>` with autogenerate columns set to true.

In the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event i change the column `Header` and `IsReadOnly` Properties as required(column bound to dictionary value is editable).

```
if ( string.Compare( e.Column.Header.ToString( ).ToLower( ), "key" ) == 0 )
            {
                e.Column.Header = "Property Name";
                e.Column.IsReadOnly = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Column.Header = "Property Value";
                e.Column.IsReadOnly = false;
            }
```

All this works as intended but when i edit a cell and tab out i get a `"Property set method not found."` message next to the cell and it does not allow me to modify the grid after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is contains a set of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` **structures**.  Now that is the problem, the `Key` and `Value` properties are readonly, there is no `Set`, even if there were what is being edited will not be the same item that is held in the dictionary since **structures** are value types.

Bottom line is you can't edit a `Dictionary` with the `DataGrid`.  You will need to create your own class:-

```
public class PropertyItem
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then use something like `ObservableCollection<PropertyItem>`.

Comment: thnx anthony that fixed the problem.